# Hex viewer with comparison on Linux

Tags: linux, diff, hex-viewer, binary-data

Is there a good Linux GUI program to view (and possibly edit) binary files in hex, and also to compare two hex files side-by-side. Ideally, it should highlight the differences, scroll the two views together, and have the possibility to reload the view if one or both file changed.

wxHexEditor seems to have most of these features, except when in compare mode, it does not update the highlighted differences correctly when a file changed. Also it seems that the comparison differences that it finds are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vbindiff](https://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/)

It has TUI, no GUI. It reloads when file changed.